# Function for Logistic Regression Training Set

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am trying to create a function to test  a logistic regression model developed on a training set.

For example

```
train <- filter(y, folds != i)
test <- filter(y, folds == i)
```

I want to be able to use the formula for different data sets. 
For example, if I were to take `y` to be a response variable such as “`low`” in the birthwt data set and `x` to be the explanatory variables e.g. `“age", “race”` how would I implement these arguments into glm.train formula without having to type the function separately for different data sets ?

```
glm.train <- glm(y ~x, family = binomial, data =  train)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reformulate` to create a formula based on strings:

```
x <- c("age", "race")
y <- "low"

form <- reformulate(x, response = y)
# low ~ age + race
```

Use this formula for `glm`:

```
glm.train <- glm(form, family = binomial, data =  train)
```